# Cypress - sudden viewport size change in test runner

Tags: cypress

I am observing a strange behaviour of the Cypress test runner GUI. It changes viewport size during test execution at a random point in time. It looks like this:
[image]

The test executes successfully, but I am not able to see it in action.
Did anyone experience similar behaviour?

EDIT:
I found out, that a certain exception appears just before the viewport collapses:
[image]

It says "(uncaught exception)Error: ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded". The test it self continues because I use

```
    Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
      return false;
    });
```

Additionally the problem apears only if I use cy.visit in a loop (cy.each or for-loop). Let´s say:

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://www.kimbino.sk'
const urls = ['/hypermarkety/', '/elektronika/', 'odev-obuv-a-sport', '/ostatne']
cy.wrap(urls).each((url) => {
  cy.visit(baseUrl + url)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes the solution is totally unexpected. I removed the experimantalStudio option from config and all works just fine. Seems like a little cypress bug.